# Generating a unique number based on records

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a situation here. I have a table which I query from my application. We don't have a unique identifier in this table.

I just need to generate unique number based on the contents of the record like ORA_HASH. I came to know that ORA_HASH returns repeatable values. So I want to know if any other option is available.

I want this because in my application we load data from the table to grid. Let's say users make some selections in grid and then sort. I want the selections to be retained. I tried using ROW_NUM as identifier. But it changes with every sort. So it'll help me a lot if I can find another way.

Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't the table have a primary key? Also please clarify whether you are trying to generate a permanent key or just a UID which remains valid for the lifetime of the grid?

Comment: Why not create another table based on the existing table to have a unique key or a primary key? This would be the right approach in moving forward.

Comment: @APC Because the data has some repeatable values that is why there is no unique key.

Comment: @APC no, not a permanent key. I just want a key which can be generated by using the content of that particular record.

Comment: Or another way of looking at it is, *the data has some repeatable values because there is no unique key*.

Comment: @user75ponic I'm afraid we cannot do that here. Even if we do as you say. It won't help here as I have repeatable data in table and I want to generate unique key for each record

Comment: Please edit you question to include some sample data and demonstrate how you expect the temporary sort key to look.

Comment: @MohammedShuaib Is it possible to have a unique key based on a combination of multiple columns?

Comment: @APC sure, give me sometime, I will come up with sample data

Comment: @user75ponic Yes, that is what I'm looking for. I'm told that ORA_HASH is unreliable. So I'm looking for other options.

Comment: @MohammedShuaib ` I just want a key which can be generated by using the content of that particular record` Here if the data in your table itself is duplicate then even selection of different columns will not help you. They will still generate the duplicate keys. Better to remove duplicates.

Comment: So in your application you have a grid. The user selects rows, then sorts and the selection is gone. That has nothing to do with SQL. Depending on the language used you may have some row addresses or references you could use or you could generate some value and fill an invisible column. If you want the query to generate such number, then Oracle's `ROWNUM` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

You keep mentioning "data that repeats" (are those *duplicates*, then?) and that being the reason for not having a unique identifier in the table.

If possible (why not?), alter table and add a new column, let's call it "ID". Populate its value *now* for existing rows, and create a database trigger which would take care about future inserts.

Here's an example:

```
SQL> create table test as select ename, job, sal from emp;

Table created.

SQL> alter table test add id number;

Table altered.

SQL> create sequence seq_id;

Sequence created.

SQL> update test set id = seq_id.nextval;

12 rows updated.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_bi_test
  2    before insert on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    :new.id := nvl(:new.id, seq_id.nextval);
  6  end;
  7  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into test (ename, job, sal) values ('Littlefoot', 'loser', 100);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test order by id;

ENAME      JOB              SAL         ID
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
SMITH      CLERK            800          1
ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600          2
WARD       SALESMAN        1250          3
JONES      MANAGER         2975          4
MARTIN     SALESMAN        1250          5
BLAKE      MANAGER         2850          6
CLARK      MANAGER         2450          7
KING       PRESIDENT       5000          8
TURNER     SALESMAN        1500          9
JAMES      CLERK            950         10
FORD       ANALYST         3000         11
MILLER     CLERK           1300         12
Littlefoot loser            100         13

13 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now you have your "unique identifier" which is *fixed* and won't change as you query data.

Answer (score 1):

Every table in oracle databases has a pseudocolumn with the name ROWID that stores a unique key for the record of the table. You should use this key for your purpose:

```
SELECT ROWID, d.* FROM dual d
```

This will give you the following Data as Result:

```
ROWID                DUMMY
------------------   -------
AAAACOAABAAAAWBAAA   X
```